# Github Graphql Filter issues which has multiple labels

Tags: graphql, github-api

This query returns those issues which has either `label1` or `label2`. Basically, It returns all the issues of `label1` and `label2`.

```
{
  repository(owner: "another-user", name: "another-repo") {
    issues(first: 100, filterBy: { labels:  ["label1", "label2"}"] }) {
      nodes {
        title
        body
        bodyHTML
        bodyText
        number
        labels(first: 100) {
          nodes {
            color
            name
            id
          }
        }
        author {
          url
          avatarUrl
          login
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to find **a specific issue** which have both `label1` and `label2` labels. How can I execute **AND** operation?

Answer (score 1):

I often see areas where "filtering" an endpoint falls short and the answer is always to use the `search` node. You can use the search API, but if you really like GraphQL there's a `search` endpoint there, too.

https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/queries#search

```
query {
   search(query: "repo:another-user/another-repo+label:label1+label:label2" type: ISSUE) {
     nodes {
       //work with nodes as usual
       __typename
       ... on Issue {
         author {
         }
         createdAt
       }
     }
   }
}
```

---

Search Query Syntax

I find the documentation a little lacking here because they do not explain the `+` syntax used in [@rbennett485](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68060029/456809)'s query, but you can infer that it is the opposite of the `-` (exclusion) to mean it *must* include the search criteria (label/repo/etc).

- [*Understanding the search syntax*](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax)

---

[GraphQL Inline Fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments)

Because the `search` node returns a "Union" ([SearchItemResultItem](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/unions#searchresultitem)) type we need to be able to switch on the particular object returned.

This is where [GraphQL Inline Fragments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments) come into play. In my example I "switch" based on the [`__typename`](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#meta-fields) of the returned node. [`__typename`](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#meta-fields) is known as a "Meta Field" and will be available in any spec compliant GraphQL server ([*GraphQL: October 2021 Edition:4.4 Type Name Introspection*](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Type-Name-Introspection)). For more see [*Introspection*](https://graphql.org/learn/introspection/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do with the graphql API other than by returning all the issues with those labels then filtering client side (docs https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/input-objects#issuefilters).

You can do it with the search API instead though https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search#search-issues-and-pull-requests.

Haven't tested but I think something like this should do the job

```
q=label:label1+label:label2+repo:another-user/another-repo
```